# Generate gif from jpeg images using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to create a gif image from a jpeg image list, everything works fine, but how can I slow the animation?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
exec('ffmpeg -f image2 -i thumb/%001d.jpg -vf scale=480x240  out.gif');
?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To slow down an image sequence, lower its framerate

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 10 -i thumb/%001d.jpg -vf scale=480x240  out.gif
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the [`-r`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-Options) flag to set the frame rate (in frames per second).  From the official documentation:

> **-r[:stream_specifier] fps (input/output,per-stream)**
>
> Set frame rate (Hz value, fraction or abbreviation).
>
> As an input option, ignore any timestamps stored in the file and instead generate timestamps assuming constant frame rate fps. This is not the same as the -framerate option used for some input formats like image2 or v4l2 (it used to be the same in older versions of FFmpeg). If in doubt use -framerate instead of the input option -r.
>
> As an output option, duplicate or drop input frames to achieve constant output frame rate fps.

For example, setting to 30 fps:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i thumb/%001d.jpg -vf scale=480x240 -r 30 out.gif
```

**Note:** The `-r` argument must appear *after* the input file if you want it to apply to the output

Comment: Works when the -r 1 setting is displayed only 2 frames. In the thumb directory I have 6 pictures I would like to display all and for everyone to display for 1 second.

Comment: Try adding `-frames:v 6` just before `out.gif`